# GStreamer Python how to release a pipeline -release all resources

Tags: python, gstreamer, pipeline, release

If this is not appropriate forum to post my question, please point me to correct forum.
I understand how to Null, pause, play and make ready a pipeline in GStreamer.
If I create and launch a pipeline and set its state to null after playing. how can I release the pipeline - unreference it gracefully- release all resources  in python so that I can loop back and recreate the pipeline with the same name?
I have searched. Is there a reference for python that lists and explains the python bindings?
In advance - thanks

Comment: Hello I tightened the loop even more. I have an external app writing images to a file. A single jpg file. Gstreamer knows when the image changes. When I detect the change, Gstreamer issues a pause, a seek to start on the pipeline and a play. The image never gets reloaded. Any suggestions on how to get the pipeline to reload the image?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.